# Google Multiplayer RealTime socket streams

Tags: android, real-time, google-play-services, multiplayer

I wonder if someone used RealTime sockets with Google Multiplayer (rather than messages).

I have a code that works OK with streams derived from  "native"(IP) socket, so I expected it to work with RealTime socket streams too. Unfortunately this is not the case.

The following code works fine with RealTime sockets

```
Sending end:
    int s1, s2;
    os.write(new byte[] {(byte)s1, (byte)s2};
    os.flush();    // May be redundant, according to Google docs
Receiving end:
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2];
    is.read(buffer);
    int r1=buffer[0] & 0xff;
    int r2=buffer[1] & 0xff;
```

However, since the length of chuck is unknown in advance, I prefer to spit the chunk into two pieces: length and the data, read one after another. Consider therefore a different code:

```
Sending end:
    byte s1, s2;
    os.write(s1);
    os.write(s2);
    os.flush();
Receiving end:
    int r1=is.read();
    int r2=is.read();
```

In this case, only first byte is read, while the second byte never comes!

Since Android docs don't recommend flush, I tried to make a wrapper for caching several writes into one on flush:

```
public class OutputStreamWrapper extends OutputStream {
    private OutputStream innerOs;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream baos;

    public OutputStreamWrapper(OutputStream innerOs) {
        this.innerOs = innerOs;
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int oneByte) throws IOException {
        baos.write(oneByte);
    }


    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        if (baos.size() > 0) 
            innerOs.write(baos.toByteArray());
        baos.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        throws IOException {
        baos.write(buffer, offset, count);
    }


    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        flush();
        innerOs.close();
        baos.close();
    }
}
```

The problem persists!

Am I doing something wrong?

If I can't find the solution, I will have to write custom streams as wrappers for Real-Time Messages, but it is really a shame to avoid "ready to use" streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer for two months... Have to answer it somehow :)

I tried several approaches, but couldn't get it working. Either the implementation of RealTime sockets is broken (BTW, I haven't come across any example of using those), or I still misunderstand something.

As a result, I found nothing better than making my own RealTime sockets by sending messages (reliable or unreliable, depending on request) under the hood.

The code is so weird that I am ashamed to publish it. But this is the idea:

1. outputStream has a BiteArrayOuputStream of size equals to max allowed size of RealTimeMessage. 
   It fires a message either on flush() or when the array is full. There is an indicator of a split packet.
2. I keep a queue of received messages. The input streams polls the queue and after the whole packet has been collected it returns the bytes.

Works great for me!